# Function after checking for Geolocation doesn't start

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I'm building a small web app that takes a form input (name) + the geolocation of the user and puts this in localstorage arrays. I'm new to JS, but I've already got the part that takes care of the name complete. I'm now trying to expand it to the point where the Latitude + Longitude get stored in a localstorage array at the moment when a user presses submit, but somehow the function that does this won't start/set through.

```
window.onload = function() {

// Read value from storage, or empty array
var names = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('locname') || "[]");
var lat = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('latitude') || "[]");
var long = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('longitude') || "[]");

function initCoords() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(saveData);
    console.log('This works');
  } else {
    showError("Your browser does not support Geolocation!");
  }
}

function saveData(data){
  console.log('But does it get here?');
  //Push Users Input value
  var data = document.getElementById("locationName").value;
  names.push(data);
  localStorage.setItem('locname', JSON.stringify(names));

  //Push Latitude
  var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
  lat.push(latitude);
  localStorage.setItem('latitude', JSON.stringify(latitude));

  //Push Longitude
  var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
  long.push(longitude);
  localStorage.setItem('longitude', JSON.stringify(longitude));
  }

document.querySelector('#saveData').onclick = initCoords;
}
```

I have a button with the id saveData. My earlier version of this script without geolocation worked perfectly, there I started the saveData function by clicking the button. In this case I first wanted to check if the user had geolocation available, therefor i created the initCoords function.

I tried to use console log to see where my function ends, it somehow doesnt get to the 'But does it get here' in saveData.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is this

> I have a button with the id saveData

you also have a function with that name

```
function saveData(data){ ....
```

If the function is in the global scope, it will be set as `window.saveData`, and then when the element with that ID comes after the function, the browser stores elements as ID's on the `window` object, so it stores `window.saveData` as the element and overwrites the function.

The solution is to change either the name of the function or the ID of the element.

**EDIT:**

Here are a few more issues:

You're not declaring `position` anywhere, you have `data` as an argument to the callback

```
function saveData(data){
  var data = document.getElementById("locationName").value;
  ....
```

That doesn't make any sense, you probably meant

```
function saveData(position){
  var data = document.getElementById("locationName").value;
  ....
```

Then there's the fact that you're storing the numbers from the position object in localStorage, not the arrays:

```
var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
  lat.push(latitude);
  localStorage.setItem('latitude', JSON.stringify(latitude));
```

See how you're pushing data to lat, but you're saving latitude, the number, not the array, so the next time around you're trying to push to a number not an array and you get an error, it should be

```
var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
  lat.push(latitude);
  localStorage.setItem('latitude', JSON.stringify(lat));
```

but now you've already stored the numbers in localStorage so you'll get an error before that you get that far in the script, you have to clear your localStorage as well, it can be done in the browser console or like this

```
localStorage.removeItem('locname');
localStorage.removeItem('latitude');
localStorage.removeItem('longitude');
```

and you have to to this once to clear it before you start trying the working code, which should look like this

```
window.onload = function () {

    localStorage.removeItem('locname');
    localStorage.removeItem('latitude');
    localStorage.removeItem('longitude');

    // Read value from storage, or empty array
    var names = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('locname') || "[]");
    var lat   = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('latitude') || "[]");
    var long  = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('longitude') || "[]");

    function initCoords() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(saveData);
            console.log('This works');
        } else {
            showError("Your browser does not support Geolocation!");
        }
    }

    function saveData(position) {
        var data = document.getElementById("locationName").value;
        names.push(data);
        localStorage.setItem('locname', JSON.stringify(names));

        var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        lat.push(latitude);
        localStorage.setItem('latitude', JSON.stringify(lat));

        var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        long.push(longitude);
        localStorage.setItem('longitude', JSON.stringify(long));

    }

    document.getElementById('saveData').onclick = initCoords;
}
```

Comment: It worked before with both the id saveData and the function named saveData. But just to be sure I changed the function to postData and the problem still occurred.

Comment: @user3708455 - looks to me like you have undefined variables, where is `position` defined ?

Comment: I wasn't sure if I needed to define it since I was following a simple example I found online where they didn't define it as well. The geolocation code (a little bit different) without the rest of the code worked fine too. I just can't seem to find out why it won't start saveData.

Comment: @TDMW - There are multiple issues, I tested it and fixed whatever I could find, see the answer above.

Comment: Your answer makes a lot of sense, and I now definitely see some things I did wrong. But the full code still isn't working somehow. I tried console logging inside the saveData function and nothing is turning up. It still seems like it isn't reaching that part of the code.

Comment: Did a popup appear asking you to confirm geolocation, and did you anwser "yes", if you've answered "no" in the past for that domain the geolocation code won't run, and the error message won't show either as geolocation is supported.

Comment: It works like a charm on your fiddle, but somehow when I run the code on my domain it isn't doing anything. Even though it's allowed to use my geolocation. I'm going to check my entire website to see where it's going wrong, thanks a lot for your answers already they made everything a lot more clear.

Comment: Can't seem to get the code from your fiddle working on my website. Even if I create a blank html page with just a button+input it isn't working. I've uploaded my project on temporary hosting I use for some other project, I'm really stuck now: http://klikcheck.com/geo/addloc.html

Comment: And did you clear the localStorage? Unless you clear the localStorage it's never going to work !

Comment: Yes I did! I got it to work now, partially. Somehow it doesn't work every time I push submit, but most of the times it does. Time for me to try and fix that error, but in the meantime thanks a lot for all your time and help! It got me super far already.